# Could not display the view using ng-if in Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need some help. I am facing some issues while loading the child view using `ng-if` in Angular.js. I am explaining my code below.

> parent.htm:

```
<div>
  <h1>Welcome</h1>
  <div ng-if="show1">
    <div ng-include="'show1.html'"></div>
  </div>
  <div ng-if="show2">
    <div ng-include="'show2.html'"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

> parentController.js:

```
var dept=angular.module('Spesh');
dept.controller('parentController',function($scope,$http,$state,$window){

    $scope.show1=true;
    $scope.show2=false;

});
```

> show1.html:

```
<div ng-controller="show1Controller">
  <h1>{{messg}}</h1>
  <button type="button" ng-click="getShow2();">show2</button>
</div>
```

> show1Controller.js:

```
var dept=angular.module('Spesh');
dept.controller('show1Controller',function($scope,$http,$state,$window){
    $scope.messg='Show1';
    $scope.getShow2=function(){
      console.log($scope);
      $scope.$parent.$parent.show1=false;
      $scope.$parent.$parent.show2=true;
    }
});
```

Here initially the `show1.html`will display and when user will click on that button the `show2.html` will display and `show1.html` will not display.

> show2.html:

```
<div ng-controller="show2Controller">
  <h1>{{messg}}</h1>
  <button type="button" ng-click="getShow2();">show1</button>
</div>
```

> show2Controller.js:

```
var dept=angular.module('Spesh');
dept.controller('show2Controller',function($scope,$http,$state,$window){
    $scope.messg='Show2';
    $scope.getShow2=function(){
      $scope.$parent.$parent.show1=true;
      $scope.$parent.$parent.show2=false;
    }
});
```

Here I can not use the `ng-show/ng-hide` because my need is to load the different controller pages as per their respective view. Here I need when user will click on the button the respective view will display. [Here is my plunkr code](https://plnkr.co/edit/OujVI3jRgvKGNEoV8VYv?p=preview) . Please help.

Comment: UGH.  If you find yourself thinking of using `$parent`, it's time to consider a refactor.  Services are usually used for this kind of inter page communication, but even `$rootScope` is better than `$parent` (though even that is questionable).  Stick to a Service.

Comment: @Claies: can you make this correct.?

Comment: However, in this case, even using `ng-if` with `ng-include` is questionable.  This is a case where using a router like `ng-route` or `ui-router` would be more appropriate.  Why are you trying to use this particular combination?

Comment: @Claies:I am using `ui-router` but for one page I need to separate for different section.

Comment: Unfortunately, this approach is definitely not going to work as expected, and there is enough wrong with how you are trying to approach this that trying to fix this would be a complete rewrite.  None of what you are showing here is usable;  using `$parent` breaks a major rule, using a primitive on `$scope` is problematic even if `$parent` wasn't a problem, and using `ng-include` on top of `ui-router` is a strange approach.  This is what nested states are for.....

Comment: @Claies: I solved it using `$rootScope`. [here is the working code](https://plnkr.co/edit/OujVI3jRgvKGNEoV8VYv?p=preview).